# Regex that checks upper or lower case characters with or without accents

Tags: php, regex, web-applications, web

How can I make the following regular expression ignore *all* whitespaces?

```
$foo = ereg_replace("[^áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑa-zA-Z]", "", $_REQUEST["bar"]);
```

**Input:** Ingeniería Eléctrica'*;<42

**Current Output:** IngenieríaEléctrica

**Desired Output:** Ingeniería Eléctrica

I tried adding /s \s\s* \s+ /\s+/ /s /t /r among others and they all failed.

**Objective:** A regex that will accept only strings with upper or lower case characters with or without (spanish) accents.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason as to why adding `\s` to that regex would not work. `\s` should match all whitespace characters.

```
$foo = preg_replace("/[^áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑa-zA-Z\s]/", "", $_REQUEST["bar"]);
```

Comment: bleh, been a while since i've used PHP. Thanks for the heads-up, have updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work

```
$foo = ereg_replace("[^áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑa-zA-Z ]", "", $_REQUEST["bar"]);
```

Comment: ereg_replace() is deprecated, you really should be recommending a switch to preg_replace()

Comment: So... simple... ~.~ Thank you !

Comment: @mark yep, you are right, but I just wanted to correct the mistake without doing anything else

Answer (score 0):

`ereg_replace` uses [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) and there, [POSIX bracket expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) are used.

Now the important thing to know is that inside bracket expressions, `\` is **not** a meta-character and therefore `\s` won't work.

But you can use the POSIX character class `[:space:]` inside the POSIX bracket expression to achieve the same effect:

```
$foo = ereg_replace("[^áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑa-zA-Z[:space:]]", "", $_REQUEST["bar"]);
```

---

You see, it is different from the, I think, better known Perl syntax and as the POSIX regular expression functions are deprecated in PHP 5.3 you really should go with the Perl compatible ones.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers so far fail to point out that your method to match the accentuated characters is a hack and it's incomplete – for instance, no grave accents are matched.

The best way is to use the mbstring extension:

```
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8"); //or whatever encoding you're using
var_dump(mb_ereg_replace("[^\\w\\s]|[0-9]", "", "Ingeniería Eléctrica'*;<42", "z"));
```

gives

```
string(22) "Ingeniería Eléctrica"
```